# What is the Time complexity of isPascal() method

Tags: performance, function, time-complexity

```
static int isPascal(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    int nthVal = 1;
    while (sum < n) {
        sum = sum + nthVal;
        nthVal++;
    }
    return sum == n ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Here the function checks given number is pascal number or not. **Pascal number** is a number that is the **sum of the integers from 1 to i for some i.**

**For example** 6 is a Pascal number because 6 = 1 + 2 + 3

What will be the Time complexity of this function? Will it be O(logn) time? If so what will be base of log here?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider calculating the square root a O(1) operation, you can do this check in O(1), with the help of the formula for the sum of the first i natural numbers

```
sum(i) = (i^2 + i)/2
```

Now in your case you don't know `i` but you know `sum(i)`, because that's your `n` you want to check if it's a pascal number. So you have

```
n = (i^2 + i) /2
```

or

```
i^2 + i - 2n = 0
```

Solving this quadratic equation with the respecitive formula gives

```
i = -1/2 + sqrt(2*n + 1/4)
```

You can discard the second solution to this equation, because `i` must be `> 0` to be a valid solution. If that resulting `i` is an integer, `n` is a Pascal number. Otherwise it isn't.

From that formula also follows, your iterative solution is in O(sqrt(n))

Comment: In my opinion the question was "What is the time complexity of my algorithm ?" not "How can I make this algorithm better ?".

Comment: @ArthurAttout If you read my last sentence, you will see, what I concluded for the complexity of OP's algorithm

Comment: And this was the only necessary sentence, which should be put on top, in bold.

Comment: @ArthurAttout When building a house, I prefer starting with the foundation and add the roof only when the walls are already built. And not to build the roof first on the ground and then put it aside, while the walls are still being built.

Comment: I'd be dubious if someone explains me how to build a full house when I just need to buy roof tiles.

Comment: @ArthurAttout  To be honest, if you don't like my answer, feel free to downvote it or come up with a better one. I always try to make my answers in a way, that I don't just say "the solution is X" but also explain WHY it's X and not Z.

Comment: I'm not downvoting that answer because it answers the question. It is just clear to me that OP has pasted a question from their exam/homework with little attempt to understand it. Because of that, trying to enhance the original question seems a bit out-of-scope IMO.

Comment: @ArthurAttout the code has not been pasted from anywhere. It was just my approach to solve the pascal number problem and after running the code successfully producing desired output, when I tried to analyze the complexity of the solution, I couldn't figure it out. That's it.